# Signature does not match : Amazon S3 bucket creation from terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket, terraform

I wanted to crete a bucket and then have something like folder1 as the folder(equivalent to create folder action in the bucket from AWS console).
I am trying to do the same with the following terraform code :

```
 resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket_create1" {
           bucket = "test_bucket/folder1/"
           acl = "private"

       }
```

I am getting the following error :

```
Error creating S3 bucket: SignatureDoesNotMatch: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Are you using Pre-signed URL?If yes Include the whole code in above Question

Comment: I am not using a pre signed URL.

Comment: Well that Error is related to usage of pre-signed URLS in S3

Answer (score -2):

Don't create folder in your bucket:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket_create1" {
    bucket = "test_bucket"
    acl = "private"
}
```

Comment: explain why plz so that this answer will help future users also